# Query Json how to get elements inside must array

Tags: c#, json, elasticsearch, json.net, json-query

I want to get elements on must array.I have query like this

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "default_operator": "and",
            "fields": [
              "entityStatusDesc"
            ],
            "query": "$entityStatusDesc"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "default_operator": "and",
            "fields": [
              "instanceStartTime"
            ],
            "query": "$instanceStartTime"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "model": {
              "query": "instance"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10,
}
```

I tried ;

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

        var acme = o.SelectToken("$.must[0]");
```

But didn't work.I want to get this part of json with must[0] call;

```
{
          "query_string": {
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "default_operator": "and",
            "fields": [
              "entityStatusDesc"
            ],
            "query": "$entityStatusDesc"
          }
        },
```

Is there any different way for getting must areas?I will be grateful if anyone could help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options is to provide full path:

```
var acme = o.SelectToken("$.query.bool.must[0]");
```

or just use indexers:

```
var acme = o["query"]["bool"]["must"][0];
```

Comment: @Orhano95 could you please accept Gurus answer? That way this post can be used as link for future duplications - and Guru gets some internet fame too ;)